# About Images and onTouch event

Tags: android, image, ontouch

I am developing an Android app that work likes sticker app, which allow user to add photo to the screen and move the photo while user touching the photo drop the photo in another position inside the screen.

May i ask if there are any approaches to achieve such effect?

What comes up in my mind now is that:

- adding imageView to Layout when i choose a photo from Gallery
- set up ontouch function for each of the imageView (is this possible to have different ontouch listener within a layout?)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and may i ask if it's possible to have numbers of imageView in the layout and have their own ontouch function?

Comment: I think it's perfectly possible, but you may have problems with ordering them correctly (top down, or z-index ordering), and if some images are transparent, they will still catch onTouch even in transparent area IIRC, so you may find out the UX a bit lacking. Where I see even bigger danger, opening many big images in Java is a sure way how to bring down the app into OOM state, so if you will use lot of decorations/etc, you will probably need to create low-res copies for manipulation time, or do the whole screen rendering in C++ native code (which can allocate more RAM on app's heap).

Comment: So to have it "perfect" you would probably want to load the images as textures in OpenGL, and create the whole manipulation and screen composition in C++ and OGL, as when creating visually intensive game. But for some initial proof-of-concept and figuring out what you need, few ImageViews are perfect, to test it out quickly.